# По ссылке href передать заполненную форму

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

Вот фрагмент jsp-страницы, где формируется таблица:

```
<div class="table_container">
<table id="clients_table" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="centered">ID</td>
        <td class="centered">Name</td>
        <td class="centered">Surname</td>
        <td class="centered">Passport</td>
        <td class="centered">Phone</td>
        <td class="centered">Account</td>
        <td class="centered">Update</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_content">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

А это фрагмент js кода, в котором заполняется таблица:

```
function fillTable() {
$.ajax('site/cmd?v',  {
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data, status) {
        console.log('STATUS: ' + status);
        console.log(data);
        $('#table_content').empty();
        data.forEach(function (client) {
            $('#table_content').append('<tr>' +
                '<td class="centered">' + client.id + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + client.name + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + client.surname + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + client.passport + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + client.phone + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + client.account + '</td>' +
                '<td><a href="site/update?id=' + client.id + '">update</a></td>' +
                '</tr>');
        })
    },
    error: function (req, status, message) {
        console.log('ERROR: ');
        console.log(message);
    }
});}
```

Последний столбец таблицы содержит атрибут `href` для перехода на другую страницу. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при нажатиии на эту ссылку, на той странице, куда указан переход, сразу создавалась форма, заполненная данными из конкретной строки таблицы?

Comment: Можно. Данные собраны, можно при нажатии их отправлять `post` методом и принимать на другой странице нужные данные.

Comment: @InDevX А не могли бы Вы более развернуто показать, как это сделать? Я всего несколько дней, как начал все это изучать и, пока слабо себе предсавляю, как это будет происходить...

Comment: В конкретно вашем случае не знаю какой сервер используете. Вот вам простой [пример](http://www.cyberforum.ru/post8601196.html) (который так же, с таблицы данные собирает) на js  которые данные отправляет на "сервер" php..